# Error On Getting Image From Firebase Storage

Tags: flutter, firebase-storage

Got This Error

> error getting token java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.google.firebase.internal.api.FirebaseNoSignedInUserException: Please sign in before trying to get a token.

I Have Change Firebase Storage Rules To Be

```
service firebase.storage {
  match /b/{bucket}/o {
    match /{allPaths=**} {
      allow read, write;
    }
  }
}
```

And Here's My Code

```
getImageFirebase(String locations, String imageName) {
  String check = "";
  check =
      storageRef.child(locations).child(imageName).getDownloadURL().toString();

  return check;
}
```

why is always need a token after i change the rules?

Answer (score 0):

you Have to update your rules like that :

```
 rules_version = '2';
 service firebase.storage {
 match /b/{bucket}/o {
 match /{allPaths=**} {
  allow read, write: if request.auth != null;
}
}}
```